# I want to close a popup. driver is unable to locate the cross(X) in the popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to click or close the popup. There is no other element which will locate and close the window. below is the error which is thrown while location the window.
I am using the code:

```
WebElement noteDisplayWindow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/button/span"));
noteDisplayWindow.click();
```

OR using css selector

```
WebElement noteDisplayWindow1=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='button'][class='ui-button']"));
noteDisplayWindow1.click();
```

This error came up when i ran CSS selector.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error:

```
Element <span class="abc xyz qwe yui"></span> is not clickable at point (968, 150). Other element would receive the click: <div class="xyz1[enter image description here][1] abc1 sdsd"></div>
```

(Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 ,platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 67 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'

Comment: "...unable to click or close the popup": what popup? Please provide some HTML.

Comment: It a pop up which come when i click on a link. and it doesnt have any button. just closing (X symbol) preasent to close the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Once try this

```
WebElement myDynamicElement=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='button'][class='ui-button']"));

new Actions(driver).moveToElement(myDynamicElement).click().perform();
```